# Estimate maximal coefficient of a polynomial from a circle containing all roots

Tags: polynomials

Suppose I have a polynomial
$$
p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n p_ix^i.
$$
For simplicity furthermore assume $p_n=1$.

As it is well known we may use Gershgorin circles to give an upper bound for the absolute values of the roots of $p(x)$. The theorem states that all roots are contained within a circle with radius
$$
r=\max\{|p_0|, 1+|p_1|,\ldots, 1+|p_{n-1}|\}.
$$

---

Now I wonder if there is something like an inverse of this theorem. Suppose I know that all roots are contained within a circle of radius $r$. Is there anything that can be said about the maximum coefficient, i.e.
$$
\max |p_i|\leq \text{some function of }r?
$$

I would also be graceful for a counter example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are actually stronger estimates that deal with all of the roots. Let $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ be the roots of your polynomial (with multiplicities as appropriate). Then 
$$
    \max_{0\le i\le n} |p_i| \ge \frac{1}{4^n} \prod_{j=1}^n \max\bigl\{|r_j|,1\bigr\}
$$
and
$$
    \max_{0\le i\le n} |p_i| \le 4^n \prod_{j=1}^n \max\bigl\{|r_j|,1\bigr\}.
$$
For references to much more general results, see the answers to [Bounds on coefficients of factors of a multivariate polynomial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151556/bounds-on-coefficients-of-factors-of-a-multivariate-polynomial/151564#151564) and [Getting a bound on the coefficients of the factor polynomial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108726/getting-a-bound-on-the-coefficients-of-the-factor-polynomial?rq=1) . (The $4^{\pm n}$ constants are not best possible.)

Answer (score 4):

Since the coefficients are $\pm 1$ times sums of products of the roots, this is obvious: for a polynomial of degree $d$ with all roots of absolute value $\le r$,

$$ |p_i| \le {d \choose i} r^{d-i} $$

The maximum of the right side is at $i = \left\lfloor \dfrac{d-r}{1+r} \right\rfloor$ or $\left\lceil \dfrac{d-r}{1+r} \right\rceil$ if $r < d$, or at $i=0$ if $r \ge d$.

Comment: Okay, that was in fact quite obvious. Thanks.